# How to re-order user profile form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have this code:

```
function mymod_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['#weight'] = 100;
}
```

Which is supposed to push the 'account' section of stuff underneath the rest of the form elements. But the weight seems to be fixed/the order is unchanged?

I've inspected the `$form` array at the point my code runs, and there are all the other fields, with their respective `#weight` values; and `100` is larger than any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight you set here would be overridden by the weight values you set via Mange Fields.

However...

You can get around this by changing the weight in pre_render.

E.g.

```
function mymod_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#pre_render'][] = 'mymod_form_alter_weight';
}

function mymod_form_alter_weight($elements) {
  $elements['account']['#weight'] = 100;

  return $elements;
}
```